# Compile error in calling a function with std::function argument

Tags: c++11, g++

The minimal code below gives me a compile error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
void print_action(function<ActionType*(Cols..., ActionType)> action_factory)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  print_action<string, uint8_t>(function<string*(uint8_t, string)>());

  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foo.cc:13:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘print_action(std::function<std::basic_string<char>*(unsigned char, std::basic_string<char>)>)’
print_action<string, uint8_t>(function<string*(uint8_t, string)>());
                                                                 ^
foo.cc:13:69: note: candidate is:
foo.cc:7:6: note: template<class ActionType, class ... Cols> void print_action(std::function<ActionType*(Cols ..., ActionType)>)
 void print_action(function<ActionType*(Cols..., ActionType)> action_factory)
      ^
foo.cc:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:13:69: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘unsigned char’
    print_action<string, uint8_t>(function<string*(uint8_t, string)>());
                                                                 ^
foo.cc:13:69: note:   ‘std::function<std::basic_string<char>*(unsigned char, std::basic_string<char>)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<std::basic_string<char>*(Cols ..., std::basic_string<char>)>’
```

I also try to change the input parameter to a simple pointer function by below code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <functional>

 using namespace std;

 template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
 void print_action(ActionType*(*action_factory)(Cols..., ActionType))
 {
 }

 string* foo_factory(uint8_t cols, string act)
 {
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   print_action<string, uint8_t>(foo_factory);
   return 0;
 }
```

It gives me the same error. After some works my last guess is that it is a bug of g++ because if I change the variadic template parameter to a simple parameter no errors happen. 
Am I right or I missed some syntax of c++?

I use g++-4.8.4 with c++11 flag(I checked it using clang-3.4 and g++-4.9.2).

**EDIT:**

If I change the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
struct Foo
{
  Foo()
  {}

  void print_action(function<ActionType*(Cols..., ActionType)> action_factory)
  {
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Foo<string, uint8_t> f;

  f.print_action(function<string*(uint8_t, string)>());

  return 0;
}
```

I get no error. I don`t understand this behavior because in both situations I defined the template parameters explicitly and I did not expect any deduction, but It seems that compiler does some deduction when it is a template function but not when it is a member function of a template class.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have `(Cols..., ActionType)`. One might think that the compiler should notice that `Cols...` should be all the arguments before the end so long as the end is the same as `ActionType`, but this is not how the language works.

A simple solution would to just deduce the entire argument list. Compilation will fail anyway if you happen to use the final argument as in a way the type doesn't support, and you could always add in a `static_assert` to ensure that the final parameter is the same as `ActionType` if you really wanted.

```
template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
void print_action(function<ActionType*(Cols...)> action_factory)
{
    //Maybe with a static_assert like this
    using LastArg = typename std::tuple_element<
                      sizeof...(Cols)-1, //number of args - 1
                      std::tuple<Cols...>
                    >::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<LastArg, ActionType>::value,
                  "The final argument must be the same type as ActionType");
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e4c8717830171a)

Comment: Your edit works because there's no template parameter deduction. There's deduction in your second example because you could pass extra arguments to the variadic parameter pack which would need to be deduced.

Comment: [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) happens when we do not specify template parameter explicitly(at least as I expected), In my first codes I specify all parameters explicitly. So still I could not understand why the compiler must try to deduce anything. Your point is correct if the parameters of outer function was different from the parameter of argument function.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz it's because variadic parameters are greedy, so any arguments supplied will be deduced as part of the pack.

Comment: Are `Cols...` in template argument of `print_action` are same as `Cols...` in `action_factory`, If they are same so your answer has a defect because number of arguments of `action_factory` is different from number of I expected unless those `Cols...` was completely different and compiler does deduction for finding `Cols...` of `action_factory` function.

Answer (score 2):

Usually variadic templates are written thus

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest> class test;
```

The compiler matches the first argument and leaves the rest (empty or more) to variadic part. The behaviour when reversed is not as expected. Variadic template arguments are *greedy*, in that, all arguments are eaten-up by it, leaving none to the last.

Your example code compiles fine, when the order is reversed:

```
template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
void print_action(function<ActionType*(ActionType, Cols...)>) {
}

int main()
{
  print_action(function<string*(string, uint8_t)>());
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf809657b041383).

There's a difference between argument type deduction and instantiation. Quote from [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://amzn.com/0201734842):

> The process of replacing template parameters by concrete types is called instantiation. It results in an instance of a template.

When a function template is instantiated, we get a function out of it; same for class/struct.

> It seems that compiler does some deduction when it is a template function but not when it is a member function of a template class.

There is no type deduction or instantiation happening for the function call. It is not a function template, but just a function. The call is just another ordinary function call.

However, the `struct` is really a `struct` template and a `struct` is created out of the template, when an object was created. For this `struct` template instantiation

```
template<typename ActionType, typename... Cols>
struct Foo;
```

the order is *correct* (the variadic argument is the last) and so it works.

Comment: Updated the answer with the reason.

Comment: My first example of calling function `print_action` I defined all parameter explicitly. I called `print_action<string, uint8_t>`, so I do not understand why a deduction must happen when all things was defined clearly. As I know [template argument deduction](en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) happens when parameter was not defined explicitly.

Comment: I understand why the class version of my example is true but my question still exists, in function template example why when I call a function with all its template parameter a deduction happens(again I emphasize that I called `print_action<string, uint8_t>`),

Comment: _why when I call a function with all its template parameter a deduction happens_: No deduction is happening! That's why I'd written that para about the difference between deduction and instantiation. It does instantiation and while trying to do that, it fails to find a matching type for `ActionType` since everything was consumed by `Cols...`.

Comment: I think I understood what you wanted to explain about instantiation and deduction, but still I have a doubt that c++ has all information it must have and I could not find any reason for difference between function and class in this situation. I reported a bug about this problem for GNU(69205) and I am waiting to get their opinion about this.